# OpenCV isn't linking properly with CMake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

```
PS C:\Users\home\OneDrive\Documents\CODE STUFF\C++\ComputerVision\build> ninja

**[2/2] Linking CXX executable ComputerVision.exe FAILED: ComputerVision.exe**

C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g  CMakeFiles/ComputerVision.dir/main.cpp.obj -o ComputerVision.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libComputerVision.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_world490d.lib"  "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_world490d.lib"  "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_world490d.lib"  "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_world490d.lib"  "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_world490d.lib"  "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_world490d.lib"  "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_world490d.lib"  "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_world490d.lib"  "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_world490d.lib"  "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_world490d.lib"  "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_world490d.lib"  "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_world490d.lib"  "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_world490d.lib"  "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_world490d.lib"  "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_world490d.lib"  "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib/opencv_world490d.lib"  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/ComputerVision.dir/main.cpp.obj: in function `main':
C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/C++/ComputerVision/main.cpp:9:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/C++/ComputerVision/main.cpp:12:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::empty() const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/C++/ComputerVision/main.cpp:18:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/C++/ComputerVision/main.cpp:21:(.text+0x120): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/C++/ComputerVision/main.cpp:24:(.text+0x125): undefined reference to `cv::destroyAllWindows()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/C++/ComputerVision/main.cpp:27:(.text+0x136): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/C++/ComputerVision/main.cpp:27:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

This is the error I get when I try to link the libraries from OpenCV into my main.cpp file. I'm not sure how I can fix this. According to the CMakeList.txt file the paths should be correct. I've even included them in the enviorment variables.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28.3)
project(ComputerVision VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

# Set the directory where OpenCV is installed
set(OpenCV_DIR "C:/Users/home/OneDrive/Documents/CODE STUFF/opencv/build")

# Print the value of OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS
message(STATUS "OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

add_executable(ComputerVision main.cpp)

# Link against OpenCV libraries
target_link_libraries(ComputerVision PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

and my main.cpp file:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Read an image file
    Mat image = imread("image.jpg");

    // Check if the image was loaded successfully
    if (image.empty()) {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Display the image
    imshow("Image", image);

    // Wait for a key press
    waitKey(0);

    // Close all OpenCV windows
    destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what to do. Honestly, I'm a noob to all of this stuff.

I've tried verifying the paths, but they seem to be correct. I think there could be something wrong with the CMakeLists.txt file, but I dont know for sure.

Comment: you're trying to link a msvc library to gcc, that won't work, you'll need a mingw build of opencv. I'd imagine you can install that from the msys package manager